# Showing a message when a field loses focus

Tags: jqgrid, qtip

I'm trying to use qtip with jqGrid and I'm not having success with this. When a field loses focus I want to show a message. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some playing around in my own projects and this looks like somthing that could be reasonable done.

Two methods depending on your exact use case / parameters.  If you want to show the qTip on the blur of a the value on the cell, then just apply a class to the value and set up your qTip accordingly.

If you want it to be on the cell itself if you were to use something like the

```
        onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
        ... //Logic to trigger the qTip on blur of the right cell

        },
```

that would let you add the logic for the qTip to be bound to the right cell of the row for the qTip blur to trigger.

While this isn't the exact code to do what you are looking for I think it is the right path to get there in two scenarios.